# Typo3 GZIP PHP error

Tags: php, gzip, typo3

since two days I got some strange characters like that

```
��]mS����%��Z鞆fL�G��vEw�֪��[[��>Q���7��nds��U����ٖ���a�����;\X�A��c5���Ҕ.�s��.��S��nհ��E�i�z�y�4|��Ŋ'��P%2�Y���.�/��]��d�J*�&�mb���Y:5�{�]������7�Ie�Ƙ��@�0��]z��BdU�6#��e%�7��_��2��k5k���i��ݨ��N��͕z�� ����XFG�t��2���pN I�_ Qi�b��i�Q�����.]�|g�*K3o�4�S@�c�)yx-������p�T�pV1ge:C�c�1��tjvc1�3����� �]�լ{�HW�=t߁a��R�fe�sE�c����LgaHlө����eh���V۷��j���V�;Ė��E�HkQ�ų��vN���p//�7x�z�˗Uv�W5�;�ȒN�lz��r����D�(?��v���=��Ų�������`Lm;nրn�T��q�$M�S�=eF$��>�y���������lN�BNn(D���
```

on my frontend. Typo3 error logs shows this error every time I reload the page. Can´t google up anything regarding this error

Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: ob_start() [ref.outcontrol]: output handler 'ob_gzhandler' conflicts with 'zlib output compression' in /home/www/web400/html/typo3/typo3/init.php line 457

It´s on a shared hosting account. I got no access to apache.

Does anybody know how to fix that?

Comment: try contacting your hosting provider, they may help you out with the configuration that is conflicting.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming problem. This is a server configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo3 provides GZIP Compression. This needs to be configurated for the specific Page you are using. If it worked before, maybe they changed (restricted) some settings.

However GZIP Compression is not required for TYPO3. You can reduce the Compression Level of the Website in /typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php or typo3conf/localconf.php (depends on typo3 version). Sometimes its also defined in a File AdditionalConfiguration.php. You have to check these for the Compression Levels. There is one for the Backend (BE) and Frontend (FE).

If your Install tool works (www.yourdomain.com/typo3/install) you can also find this Setting there.

Comment: this worked. but now there are some strange php errors. sry but can you please have a short look on http://www.fahrschule-list.ch/

Comment: Since the Website is .ch I assume you can understand German. 
http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-german/2007-February/028834.html

What you see, are Warnings. Those can, and to be hones should be, disabled in the Webserver Configuration. On the proviced Mailings Page, they Tell you that those are Warnings and they Say something about the Error Reporting is set to E_ALL. This has to be fixed. For further problems I would recommend Googling for those specific errors. Maybe clear the Cache and check if the Files are in the right domain Space.

Comment: Called my incompetent hoster and he fixed it. ty for helping!